# Laravel get sum of all records of rows from database

Tags: database, laravel

[image]

Look at the above image.

What I want is create a table of weekly data from using above db. 
From past week the (from today to 7 days before). The table should contain `dish_name` , Sum of `quantity` for past week, sum of `price` for past week group by `dish_name`.

Can anyone give a solution for this. (Using Laravel `5.7`)

```php
$today = Carbon::now();
$one_week_ago = Carbon::now()->subWeeks(1);
$something = BillPaid::where('created_at', '>=', $one_week_ago)
        ->where('created_at', '<=', $today)
        ->select('dish_name', 'quantity')->groupBy('dish_name')->get();
```

The Problem isn't getting dates. I can clearly get products from above query. I have no idea what I have to do after that. From above image, I attached, the past week goes from `2018-12-28 to 2018-12-21` so all records from that image should includes.

What I want is make a table like:

```php
"vege rice" , 3 (quatation), 600(price) , 
"Chicken Fried rice", 9(quatation), 3150 (price)
```

Comment: It's expected that you show some code attempts yourself before asking someone to write the code for you.

Comment: I edited  the post. I've seen some using raw in laravel. But I couldn't understand how to use it for this.

Comment: You could use whereBetween (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses), that should help.

Comment: why dnt used `beetwen`???

Comment: @Adam The Problem is not getting dates. I can clearly get products from above query. I have no idea what I have to do after that. From above image I attached the past week goes from 2018-12-28 to 2018-12-21 so all records from that image should includes. What I want is make a table "vege rice" , 3 (quatation), 600(price) , "Chicken Fried rice", 9(quatation), 3150 (price)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```php
$today = Carbon::now();
$one_week_ago = Carbon::now()->subWeeks(1);
$something = BillPaid::selectRaw('dish_name,SUM(price) as totalPrice,SUM(quantity) as totalQuantity')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$one_week_ago, $today])
    ->groupBy('dish_name')->get();
```

Comment: I edited the post. The problem isn't getting dates. I want to sum of quentities and prices which I don't know how to do.

Comment: try this now this code i add `selectRaw` and put sum price and quantity

Comment: Glad to hear that @Gayath_chandi. Please, mark the question as solved.